# Setting focus on an HTML input box on page load

Tags: javascript, html, focus, onload, autofocus

I'm trying to set the default focus on an input box when the page loads (example: google).
My page is very simple, yet I can't figure out how to do this.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Password Protected Page</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function FocusOnInput()
 {
 document.getElementById("PasswordInput").focus();
 }
 </script>

 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  body, html {height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
  #outer {width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
  #middle {vertical-align: middle}
  #centered {width: 280px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align:center;}
 </style>
</head>
<body onload="FocusOnInput()">
 <table id="outer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td id="middle">
   <div id="centered">
  <form action="verify.php" method="post">
   <input type="password" name="PasswordInput"/>
  </form>
   </div>
  </td></tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

How come that doesn't work while this works fine?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function FocusOnInput()
{
     document.getElementById("InputID").focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="FocusOnInput()">
  <form>
       <input type="text" id="InputID">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Help is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This line:

```
<input type="password" name="PasswordInput"/>
```

should have an **id** attribute, like so:

```
<input type="password" name="PasswordInput" id="PasswordInput"/>
```

Comment: Will that actually set the input focus? Which browser did you try it on?

Comment: @PeterMortensen when I tested this 9 years ago was on firefox, chrome and ie :)

Answer (score 387):

And you can use HTML5's autofocus attribute (works in all current browsers except IE9 and below). Only call your script if it's IE9 or earlier, or an older version of other browsers.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" autofocus />
```

Comment: ie9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280988/how-to-make-input-autofocus-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @BhaveshGangani [`autofocus` is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

Comment: Here's a compatibility table for **autofocus**: https://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus

Comment: I swear without this website I would be 90 years old already because I'd spend all my time researching.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the common issues with IE and fix for this is simple. 
Add .focus() twice to the input.

Fix :-

```
function FocusOnInput() {
    var element = document.getElementById('txtContactMobileNo');
    element.focus();
    setTimeout(function () { element.focus(); }, 1);
}
```

And call FocusOnInput() on $(document).ready(function () {.....};

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
<body onload="focusOnInput()">
    <form name="passwordForm" action="verify.php" method="post">
        <input name="passwordInput" type="password" />
    </form>
</body>
```

And then in your JavaScript:

```
function focusOnInput() {
    document.forms["passwordForm"]["passwordInput"].focus();
}
```