# JQuery Date Slider in SAPUI5 application

Tags: sapui5, jquery-ui-slider

I have a custom SAPUI5 in which I want to use slider for date picker, I found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466851/javascript-slider-that-scrolls-along-both-dates-and-times#)

I have included `iquery-ui` lib in `Controller.js` (as we will run app in Fiori Launchpad). And included the JS code from indicated post in `onAfterRendering()`, which is recommended to use instead of `$(document).ready` by UI5.

When I run the app - it says `TypeError: $(...).slider` is not a function, although I see in Network tab `jquery-ui.js` is being loaded.

I tried also to make it work from `index.html` - then there is no error in console, just the slider is absent.

Can someone please advice?

This is my code in onAfterRendering function

```
$('.slider-time').html(dt_from);
$('.slider-time2').html(dt_to);
var min_val = Date.parse(dt_from) / 1000;
var max_val = Date.parse(dt_to) / 1000;

function zeroPad(num, places) {
var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}

function formatDT(__dt) {
var year = __dt.getFullYear();
var month = zeroPad(__dt.getMonth() + 1, 2);
var date = zeroPad(__dt.getDate(), 2);
var hours = zeroPad(__dt.getHours(), 2);
var minutes = zeroPad(__dt.getMinutes(), 2);
var seconds = zeroPad(__dt.getSeconds(), 2);
return year + '-' + month + '-' + date + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
};

$("#slider-range").slider({
range: true,
min: min_val,
max: max_val,
step: 10,
values: [min_val, max_val],
slide: function (e, ui) {

var dt_cur_from = new Date(ui.values[0] * 1000); 
$('.slider-time').html(formatDT(dt_cur_from));

var dt_cur_to = new Date(ui.values[1] * 1000);                 
$('.slider-time2').html(formatDT(dt_cur_to));
```

Comment: Edited the post above with slider function from Controller.

Comment: Maybe it would help in debugging the issue, if you could create a sample in a tool like https://plnkr.co/ .

Is there a special reason why you are using slider for date picker?
Are you familiar with the UI5 samples for [Date Picker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DatePicker/preview) and [Date Time Picker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.DateTimePicker/preview) ?
You can also download the coding of these samples.

Comment: Hi. The application has a time span of 24 hours - so slider is just a much more comfortable tool than datetime picker. I have added code to plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/bjG8Fo2pXg8QE24YcvFD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your example on plunkr.
I’m still debugging, but I’m also wondering:
Is there a special reason, why you are not using the TimePickerSliders-control from SAPUI5 or
the Slider-control, which is available in both SAPUI5 and OpenUI5 ?

You could save some of your own coding and the design might be more Fiori-like.
I modified the “content” of your Main.view.xml in the following way:

```
<sap.ui.core.mvc:View controllerName="view.Main"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:sap.ui.core.mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="Slider">
        <content>

    <Text text="TimePickerSliders" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
    <TimePickerSliders
      id="TPS2"
      valueFormat="hh:mm:ss a"
      displayFormat="HH:mm:ss"
      change="handleChange"
      height="400px"
      support2400="true"/>

    <Text text="Slider with tickmarks and labels" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
    <Slider min="0" max="60" enableTickmarks="true" value="30" width="90%" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom">
      <ResponsiveScale tickmarksBetweenLabels="5"/>
    </Slider>
    <Text text="Minutes" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>

    <Slider min="0" max="24" enableTickmarks="true" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom" width="90%">
      <ResponsiveScale tickmarksBetweenLabels="1"/>
    </Slider>
    <Text text="Hours" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
        </content>
    </Page>
</sap.ui.core.mvc:View>
```

Would this be acceptable for your requirement ?