# Can the cursor go directly to the input when the web page is on?

Tags: javascript, html

I was asked to develop a web page without a mouse.
The keyboard cursor must be in the input area(example: `<input id="input-label" type="text">`) immediately when the page is changed.

I tried,

```
document.querySelector("#input-area").focus();
```

and

```
document.querySelector("#input-area").select();
```

It works with buttons, but does not work in `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  document.querySelector("#input-area").select();
});
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why not `<input autofocus>`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. thanks! It works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383429/setting-focus-on-an-html-input-box-on-page-load#3383468 Duplicate question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting focus on an HTML input box on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383429/setting-focus-on-an-html-input-box-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

try this, call it when dom is ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#input-area").focus();
});
```

**OR**

```
 <input id="input-area" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

**OR**

```
$(function() {
  $("#input-area").focus();
});
```

Comment: Whats the error in console ... did you include jquery ? @Centell

Comment: yep, jquery included. I tried .ready either. and no errors appear.. I can't understand why id doesn't work. but the `autofocus` works well. It only need `<input id="input-area" autofocus>`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myAnchor').click(function() {
        $('#mustfocus').focus();
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="myAnchor" value="Get focus">
<input type="text" id="mustfocus"/>


</body>
</html>
```

**How about this one which triggers only during DOM is ready:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mustfocus').focus();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="myAnchor" value="Get focus">
<input type="text" id="mustfocus"/>


</body>
</html>
```